# ECharts disable symbol (marker) animation only

Tags: animation, symbols, echarts

Take a look at this simple demo project I grabbed from their site:
https://ecomfe.github.io/echarts-examples/public/editor.html?c=dynamic-data2

Only thing I changed is the value of `showSymbol`. From false to true. So you can see the little dots on the line and how they slowly grow until they reach their final size. Since I can't save my own version of this demo you'll have to do so aswell to see what I mean.

There is a property called `animation` for series. This will in fact disable the grow animation, but will also disable all other animations connected with this series. For example the smooth transition to the left when new datapoints are added.

I don't want to hide the markers. I want them there, but without that animation.

Does anyone know of a way to achive this?

Answer (score 6):

```js
    series: [{
        name: '模拟数据',
        type: 'line',
        showSymbol: true,
        hoverAnimation: false,
        data: data,
        animation: false
    }],
    animation: true
```

This can help disable the item animation while keeping animation of the X axis. But I'm afraid there's nothing more we can do with the line animation.